# Prestashop Repository not found

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Good morning.

i have a problem using the new Symfony architecture.
i created a modern controller where routing is working perfect.
now i want to search products with ProductRepository.

MyModule/src/Repository/ProductRepository

```
namespace PrestaShop\Module\MyModule\Repository;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class ProductRepository
{
/**
 * @var Connection the Database connection.
 */
private $connection;

/**
 * @var string the Database prefix.
 */
private $databasePrefix;



/**
 * @param int $langId the lang id
 * @return array the list of products
 */
public function findAllbyLangId(int $langId)
{
    $prefix = $this->databasePrefix;
    $productTable = "${prefix}product";
    $productLangTable = "${prefix}product_lang";

    $query = "SELECT p.* FROM ${productTable} p LEFT JOIN ${productLangTable} pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`) WHERE pl.`id_lang` = :langId";
    $statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue('langId', $langId);
    $statement->execute();

    return $statement->fetchAll();
 }
```

}

MyModule/config/services.yml

```
services:
   product_repository:
   class: PrestaShop\Module\MyModule\Repository\ProductRepository
   arguments: ['@doctrine.dbal.default_connection', '%database_prefix%']
```

MyController

```
$products = $this->get('product_repository')->findAllByLangId(1);
dump($products);
```

Now i get the following error: 
"Attempted to load class "ProductRepository" from namespace "PrestaShop\Module\MyModule\Repository".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"

What im missing there?
Thx for your time and help.

update - Stacktrace:

```
**ClassNotFoundException**
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException:
Attempted to load class "ProductRepository" from namespace 
"PrestaShop\Module\EasyUpload\Repository".
 Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

 at var\cache\dev\ContainerZiol6qc\getProductRepositoryService.php:8
 at require()
 (var\cache\dev\ContainerZiol6qc\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:1713)
 at ContainerZiol6qc\appDevDebugProjectContainer->load('getProductRepositoryService.php')(vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:304)
at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('product_repository')
 (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait.php:67)
at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->get('product_repository')
 (modules\easyupload\src\Controller\DemoController.php:111)
at EasyUpload\Controller\DemoController->search()
 (modules\easyupload\src\Controller\DemoController.php:76)
at EasyUpload\Controller\DemoController->indexAction(object(Request), null)(vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php:151)
at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)

(vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php:68)
at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, false)
  (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:200)
at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request), 1, false)
 (admin108ptrz6g\index.php:86)`
```

Comment: I suppose - but not sure, I don't work with prestashop, that `ProductRepository` should extends `ServiceEntityRepository` looking at your configuration.

Comment: The demo [link]https://github.com/PrestaShop/productcomments/blob/master/src/Repository/ProductCommentRepository.php says not to extend.

Comment: Can you edit your question including whole stacktrace for this exception?

Comment: Done. Dont worry about different Module Name. Thats only for here and not the problem. :)

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes, i cleared both, dev and prod. Im wondering about the Stacktrace ->load('getProductRepositoryService.php') - this is not my File. Ah ok, this file exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's look like you didn't create composer.json file with predefined namespaces.

Here example:

```
{
  "name": "YourName/YourModuleName",
  "description": "Awesome description",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "YourName\\YourModuleName\\": "/",
      "YourName\\YourModuleName\\Repository": "src/Repository/",
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "prepend-autoloader": false
  },
  "type": "prestashop-module"
}
```

OR if you want with Prestashop right way

```
{
  "name": "YourName/YourModuleName",
  "description": "Awesome description",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Prestashop\\Module\\YourModuleName": "src/",
      "Prestashop\\Module\\YourModuleName\\Repository": "src/Repository/",
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "prepend-autoloader": false
  },
  "type": "prestashop-module"
}
```

Then run `composer install` and add to your YourModuleName.php file require_once.

```
$autoloadPath = __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
if (file_exists($autoloadPath)) {
    require_once $autoloadPath;
}
```

Comment: Thats the correct answer. I created a composer.json, but declared only the controller folder there. Thx for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for hours and find out I needed this exact structure to register the mycompany.mymodule.myservice. This has to be exactly like this in Prestashop 1.7.6:

// mycompany\mymodule\config

- config

  - admin

    - services.yml
  - front

    - services.yml
  - common.yml

Also make sure your namespace is setup correctly.